# Troubleshooting getting started with Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Just started writing my first Spring 5 codes.  Managed to compile and run the code, but nothing gets printed out.

The output from terminal shows the below:
17:22:47.103 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'baos'
17:22:47.150 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'printStream' to allow for resolving potential circular references
17:22:47.150 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'printStream'
17:22:47.241 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'helloGreeter'
17:22:47.241 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'printStream'
17:22:47.241 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'baos'
17:22:47.243 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@2892d68]
17:22:47.243 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
17:22:47.248 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain' in any property source
17:22:47.258 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'helloGreeter'

Any advise is greatly appreciated:

```
src/main/java/com/apress/beginspring5/Main.java
===
package com.apress.beginspring5.ch2;

import com.apress.beginspring5.ch2.annotated.Greeter;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/applicationContext.xml");

        Greeter greeter = context.getBean("helloGreeter", Greeter.class);
        greeter.greet();
    }
}


src/main/java/com/apress/beginspring5/HelloGreeter.java
===
package com.apress.beginspring5.ch2;

import com.apress.beginspring5.ch2.annotated.Greeter;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.PrintStream;

@Service("helloGreeter")
public class HelloWorldGreeter implements Greeter {

    private PrintStream printStream = System.out;

    public void setPrintStream(PrintStream printStream) {
        this.printStream = printStream;
    }

    public void greet() {
        printStream.print("Hello, World!");
    }

}


src/main/java/com/apress/beginspring5/annotated/Greeter.java
===
package com.apress.beginspring5.ch2.annotated;

import java.io.PrintStream;

public interface Greeter {

    void setPrintStream(PrintStream printStream);

    void greet();
}


src/main/resources/spring/applicationContext.xml
===
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<!-- tag::beans[] -->
    <bean id="helloGreeter" class="com.apress.beginspring5.ch2.HelloWorldGreeter">
        <property name="printStream" ref="printStream" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="printStream" class="java.io.PrintStream">
        <constructor-arg ref="baos"/>
        <constructor-arg value="true"/>
        <constructor-arg value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="baos" class="java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream" />
<!-- end::beans[] -->

</beans>
```

Comment: This is a bit weird and it looks like perhaps you took a sample code that is very old. Spring has ditched the xml configuration files for a while now. You'd inject the Greeter into Main using the @Autowired annotation. 
Also, though debatable, you could get rid of that interface Greeter if you will only have one implementation.

Comment: Thanks @fpezzini for your comments.  But I think it is not wrong to use xml configuration file here.

Comment: have you tried the code from the repo https://github.com/kinabalu/bsg5